# Are there CDN for streaming video content with custom configuration of media servers

Tags: cdn, video-streaming, flash-media-server

My company currently is using CloudFront as Content Distribution Network.

But recently we need some additional configuration to the media server they are using for streaming our video content. But... Amazon does not provide such service, we couldn't obtain access to the FMS configurations.

We need VideoSampleAccess property of the streamed content to be set to TRUE, which (for security reasons) currently is set to FALSE.

My question is: Are there any CDNs providing custom configuration of their media servers?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to contact some content delivery providers and ask them. Since the default setting is `off`, it is unlikely that a provider will change it just for you.

Comment: We have already tried that. No luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

While, perhaps not the ideal setup, Amazon will let you 'license' a copy of Flash Media server for a monthly fee ($5) (plus, of course, instance costs), which you can then customize and run how you like on your server. The setup is commonly used for live-streaming, but it should be possible to adapt it to what you are looking for. It works in conjunction with 'CloudFormation' (for setup) and 'CloudFront' (as the CDN). It comes pre-configured, and you have SSH access to modify whatever you need (they explicitly state 'manifest.xml', but that should apply to 'application.xml' as well).

Take a look at the following:

- [Live Streaming using Cloudfront](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/FeaturedArticles/latest/index.html?LiveStreamingUsingAmazonCloudFront.html)
- [FMS on AWS](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/amazonwebservices/)

Comment: We are aware of these possibilities, it will cost us some amount of time/money but seems that currently we have no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

I work for [Rambla](http://rambla.eu), a European CDN service provider. We regularly set up custom streaming applications for our customers (using Wowza, though), both for live and on-demand streaming. This setting can be configured at application level, so I don't see why a service provider shouldn't be able to change it for you.

Comment: Do you provide your service only in Europe, or all over the world?